# Powershell Call-Operator(&) with Parameters from Variable

Tags: powershell

G'day everyone,

I'm trying to execute a function in PowerShell with the Parameters coming from a Variable I'm not sure if it's possible in the way I want it to but maybe someone has any idea how I would go about doing that.

```
$scriptPath = "C:\temp\Create-File.ps1"
$parameters = "-Path C:\temp\testfile.txt -DoSomethingSpecial"

& $scriptPath $parameters
```

Something along those lines, I don't know in which order the Parameters get entered so I can't use $args[n..m] or binding by position for that. Maybe there is some other Cmdlet I don't know about that is capable of doing that?

Comment: Could you use a `hash table` for the parameters?

Comment: Yes that would work with some string Manipulation - how would I go about passing that in?

Comment: Use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a hastable and [Splatting](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/10/18/use-splatting-to-simplify-your-powershell-scripts/) to do this.

Simply set each param name and value in the variable as you would a normal hastable, then pass this in using `@params` syntax.

The switch param however, needs a `$true` value for it to function correctly.

```
$params = @{
    Path               = 'C:\temp\testfile.txt'
    DoSomethingSpecial = $true
}

.\Create-File.ps1 @params
```

Comment: That worked like a charm - I didnt even know this existed. Thank you!

Comment: how would i pass a Verb ? e.g    `myfile.exe -named_param named_value verb1 verb2`

Comment: @TomerW Just quote the entire thing: `@{ named_param = "named_value verb1 verb2" }`

Comment: @JamesC. That pases `-named_param "named_value verb1 verb2"`...
BUT I found that using Array instead of Object as `@("-named_param", "named_value","verb1","verb2")` works well and is more versatile for different conventions of param syntax.

Answer (score 8):

Passing an Object as @James C. suggested in his answer allows only to pass parameters in Powershell syntax (e.g. `-param1 value1 -param2 value2`)

When you need more control over the parameters you pass such as:

- double dash syntax for unix style `--param1 value1`
- Slash syntax for Windows style `/param1 value1`
- Equals sign required (or colon) `-param1=value1` or `-param1:value1`
- No value for parameter `-boolean_param1`
- additional verbs (values without a param name) `value1 value2`

you can use an array instead of an object

take `ipconfig` command for example to renew all connections with "con" in their name:

```
$cmd = "ipconfig"
$params = @('/renew', '*Con*');
& $cmd $params
```

or the specific question given example:

```
$params = @('-Path', 'C:\temp\testfile.txt', '-DoSomethingSpecial')
.\Create-File.ps1 @params
```

Answer (score 2):

You can run it by Start-Process

```
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "$scriptPath $parameters"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution with minimal change to the original:

```
$scriptPath = "C:\temp\Create-File.ps1"
$parameters = "-Path C:\temp\testfile.txt -DoSomethingSpecial"

& $scriptPath $parameters.Split()
```