# Illegal characters in path - dacpac deployment via SqlPackage.exe

Tags: powershell, sql-server-data-tools

I'd like to call `SqlPackage.exe` using [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.3) but I'm doing something wrong as I get an error:

> Illegal characters in path.

```
$FilePath = 'C:\some path\SqlPackage.exe'
$ArgumentList = @(
    '/Action:Publish'
    '/SourceFile:"C:\some path\blah.dacpac"'
    '/TargetConnectionString:"Server=localhost; Database=Blah; Trusted_Connection=True;"'
)
& $FilePath $ArgumentList
```

[Following this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55548179/185123), it would seem I need to use array splatting, correct?

The problem seems to be dealing with the parameter convention of SqlPackage, `/[name]:"[value]"`, specifically the double quotes.

And how do I deal w/ dynamic values? i.e.:

```
$Blah = 'blah.dacpac'
$ArgumentList = @(
    '/Action:Publish'
    '/SourceFile:"C:\some path\$Blah"'
    '/TargetConnectionString:"Server=localhost; Database=Blah; Trusted_Connection=True;"'
)
```

Reference: [SqlPackage Publish Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-publish?view=sql-server-ver16#examples)

Answer (score 1):

Your command *should* work:

- In *Windows PowerShell* and [*PowerShell (Core)*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) *v7.2-*:

  - By default.
  - The raw process command line constructed behind the scenes looks like this:

    ```
    "C:\some path\SqlPackage.exe" /Action:Publish /SourceFile:"C:\some path\blah.dacpac" /TargetConnectionString:"Server=localhost; Database=Blah; Trusted_Connection=True;"
    ```
- In *PowerShell (Core) 7.3+*:

  - Only if you (temporarily) set the [`$PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#psnativecommandargumentpassing) to `'Legacy'`.
  - *Otherwise* (with value `'Windows'` (the default) or `'Standard'`), the raw process command line looks like this - note the overall `"..."` enclosure of some of the arguments and how *embedded* `"` chars. are escaped as `\"`:

    ```
    "C:\some path\SqlPackage.exe" /Action:Publish "/SourceFile:\"C:\some path\blah.dacpac\"" "/TargetConnectionString:\"Server=localhost; Database=Blah; Trusted_Connection=True;\""
    ```

See:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74440425/45375) for background information.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77349130/45375) to your previous question for how you can examine the raw process line that PowerShell ends up constructing behind the scenes.

Therefore:

```
& {
  $PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing = 'Legacy' # Needed in v7.3+
  $FilePath = 'C:\some path\SqlPackage.exe'
  $ArgumentList = @(
    '/Action:Publish'
    '/SourceFile:"C:\some path\blah.dacpac"'
    '/TargetConnectionString:"Server=localhost; Database=Blah; Trusted_Connection=True;"'
  )
  & $FilePath $ArgumentList
}
```